# How to hide the scrollbar (whilst being able to scroll) in FireFox browser?

Tags: html, css, firefox

How to hide the scrollbar (whilst being able to scroll) in FireFox browser or is there 1 piece of code that hides the scrollbar (whilst being able to scroll) in all browsers.

Since

```
scrollbar-width: none;
```

is no longer working I am searching for something that works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
html{
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

Works to hide the scrollbar while still being able to scroll on the whole page. Use a different selector to target a specific element.

(I just tested it and it still works on firefox. [caniuse for reference](https://caniuse.com/?search=scrollbar-width))

Same functionality for other browsers:

```
//For Chrome, Safari and Opera
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

//For IE and Edge
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
```